# Best javascript practice to compare two arrays and find items that are present in the second and missing in first

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two different arrays:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [2,4,6]
```

I would like to get a new array that contain all the elements of B that are not presents in A.

Comment: Take a look at [`_.difference`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#difference)

Comment: I suggest doing set operation using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Implementing_basic_set_operations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write :

```js
const A = [1,2,3,4,5];
const B = [2,4,5];

const diff = [];
const flag = true;

A.map( val => {
   if(!B.includes(val)) {
       flag = false;
       diff.push(val)
   }
});

console.log(flag)
console.log('elem present in A but not in B:');
console.log(diff);
```

if you want to know if all elems of B are in A, you can do it with a one liner :

```
// true if all elem of B are in A else false
let flag = B.reduce((acc,val) => A.includes(val) ? acc && true : false, true);
```

Comment: As i mention in the question, I need to get the lements of the B array that are missing in the A one...

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the suggestion, I got the solution from it but please edit your answer after reading well my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple filtering as follow:

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5]
const b = [2,3,4]
    
const c = a.filter(v => b.indexOf(v) < 0);
console.log(c);
```

This will take array `a` and filter out everything that already exist inside of `b` by using `indexOf`.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, I need to get the elements of the B array that are missing into the A one...

Comment: @EdoardoCalderoni Just swap the variable names `a` and `b` and you got your answer :)